# How do I get both integer and string from the user

Tags: java, string, integer

How can I get this when the user enters a mixed input.

We use this for integer:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = input.nextInt();
```

We use this for String:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = input.next();
```

How can we use both of them at once?
For example: password123
How can i save it?

I think I should use the java generic class.I searched for Java Gneric, but I did not understand.

Thank you.

Comment: password123 is string, so u need to use input.next();

Comment: OP is looking for a more generic solution across different input types.

Comment: Save both of what? A scanner detects string patterns and can only return one type.

Comment: you should save the string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password123` is a string, that happens to contain numbers.

So using this should work:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = input.next();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I save without knowing the type of input the user has entered?

Comment: @uyusuk what do you mean?

Comment: OP is looking for a more generic solution across different input types.

Comment: Sorry my english's not good. 'String name'  only saves the String.How can I save input without knowing data type?
example: <datatype> input . The input variable must be able to store both integer and string data.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Okay :/ Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

solution: treat all input as String, since you don't know what you're going to get from user. later convert to int or whatever if you need to, if you have more context about what the data represents.

Answer (score 0):

A Scanner can only return one type at a time. If you have multiple inputs, then, you prompt for input more than once

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Your name is: ");
String name = input.next();
System.out.print("Your age is: ");
int age = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to put it first to String. because when you have a word with numbers like `password123`, it will only be a **String** because you can't have an **Integer** with a word or a letter.